# Increase Python's stdout buffer size

Tags: python

Is there a way to increase the `stdout` buffer size from *8182* in Python
***or***
to delay the flush until I actually call `flush`?

Things I've tried that don't work:

- I can get around this issue on Windows because I can access the buffer directly (e.g. [see my answer to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19594702/c-stop-stdout-from-flushing/65020385#65020385)). But this doesn't work for Unix.
- I can increase the buffer size for a file by passing `buffer` to the constructor, however `stdout` is already constructed.
- [Turning off buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering) (`python -u`) obviously makes things worse!
- Using a temporary buffer encounters the same problems - `stdout` is flushed after every 8192nd byte is copied from the temporary buffer.

Rationale: The aim here is to reduce console flickering. Buffering everything, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842526/update-console-without-flickering-c) indeed works, for instance when I try in C or by using the Windows API in Python, but the 8182 limit in Python seems to be causing problems that I can't get around on Unix.

Comment: I'd like to know why you need to do this :)

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It sounds like you might be better served by some other approach, such as doing your own buffering.

Comment: "Using a temporary buffer encounters the same problems when the temporary is ultimately copied to stdout." - what problems?

Comment: It sounds like you should have asked a question about avoiding terminal flickering, not a question about buffer size adjustment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/107717/7256228

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Re: *"should have asked a question about avoiding terminal flickering"* - [That question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842526/update-console-without-flickering-c) is what led me here haha. I've updated my question with the source, but maybe this would be useful for someone else anyway, I presume the `FileIO` `buffer` argument exists for a reason.

Comment: @cz I was referring the other thing explained in that answer. To quote `You could also replace sys.stdout with some other stream like wrapper which does a flush after every call.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer, actually very simple:

```
my_stdout = open( 1, "w", buffering = 100000 )
```

- `1` is the `fileno` for `stdout`.
- `sys.stdout = my_stdout` can be used to make the change to the default `print` target.
- I've only tested this on Unix.

Answer (score 5):

You can wrap the raw stdout stream, available as `sys.stdout.buffer`, with a larger buffer size with `io.BufferedWriter`, and then wrap the resulting buffered binary stream as a buffered text stream with `io.TextIOWrapper`:

```
import io
import sys

sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedWriter(sys.stdout.buffer, new_size))
```

Here's a demonstration of the effect of increasing the buffer size of stdout to 100000 so that it does not flush the two 10000-character-long print outputs until a manual flush is called:

```
import io
import sys
import time

print('Original buffer size:', io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)
for large_buffer in False, True:
    if large_buffer:
        print('Increasing buffer size...')
        sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedWriter(sys.stdout.buffer, 100000))
    for i in range(2):
        time.sleep(2)
        print(str(i * 2) * 10000)
        time.sleep(2)
        print(str(i * 2 + 1) *10000)
        print(f'Flush #{i + 1}')
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/UnkemptGullibleDecompiler

Comment: Thanks, but this just holds the data in `BufferedWriter` until you call `sys.stdout.flush`. When `BufferedWriter` pushes to the *real* stdout, it still has same underlying problem - it flushes for every 8182nd byte written (from the `BufferedWriter`). That said I notice this considerably improves application performance (if not the flickering) when writing to a slow terminal such as in PyCharm.