# Is Python's `print()` function blocking or non-blocking?

Tags: python, blocking, nonblocking

I'm trying to speed up the processing time of a script, which in certain configurations may have a lot of output dumped to the console (file=stdout) via `print()`.  Is Python's `print()` function blocking or non-blocking?  I've not able able to find an adequate answer for this in the documentation.

I'm running Linux 4.18.0-486.el8.x86_64 GNU/Linux.

Comment: It depends entirely on what file you are printing *to*. `print` is a wrapper that does some basic string formatting to its arguments before passing that result to the `write` method of whatever object was specified with the `file` keyword argument.

Comment: Related: If stdout is an interactive terminal, you will likely get the buffer described here: https://superuser.com/questions/1195103/ptys-pseudo-terminals-internal-buffer-size And if you redirect stdout to a file or pipe, it will be fully buffered (approx. 4 kiB) with blocking IO as with any regular file output

Comment: Do you mean *blocking* or *buffered*? They're different concepts but it seems like you might be referring to the latter.

Comment: Also, you should specify what OS you are using, as the blocking and buffering behaviours will not always be the same between OSes.

Comment: You might consider switching to the `logging` module, then you can choose your volume of output (i.e. logging level) and whether you want it on the terminal, in a file or sent to system-wide logger at runtime. See https://pymotw.com/3/logging/index.html

Comment: @chepner This is in regards to writing to stdout.  (I've updated the original post.)

Comment: @Woodford My assumption was that the data for stdout was being buffered somewhere (it would seem to be a necessity), but I'm unsure if `print()` just buffers it and returns, or waits for that buffer / write-to-console to complete before returning.

Comment: @JimFell, "writing to stdout" doesn't quite answer the question. It's _blocking_ insofar as it isn't async, but it's _buffered_ by default insofar as the libc write calls store data up instead of always invoking a syscall immediately. So we need to know what specific behavior you mean when you say "blocking". Do you mean blocking _until the content is in the kernel_, or do you mean blocking _until the content is handed off to libc_?

Comment: If stdout is blocking, then `print` will block; if stdout is non-blocking, `print` will not block. It's the *file* that matters, not `print` itself.

Comment: Mind, by default, stdout is line-buffered when it points to a TTY, and by default print appends newlines; so unless you override the addition of newlines or stdout is directed to a non-file sink, the default behavior you get is _much like_ unbuffered output in many circumstances.

Comment: @JimFell, ...so, what's the specific guarantee you're looking for presence or lack of when you use the word "blocking"?

Comment: I'm just trying to whittle down the processing time.  If `print()` just copies the string to a buffer and then returns, okay, that's fine for now.  If it's waiting on anything (e.g. console to update, buffer to handoff, etc) then that's a problem that I need to address.

Comment: In that case you care about _buffering_, not just blocking, and the answer is "it depends" -- among other things, on what kind of destination stdout is pointed to.

Comment: Mind, if it's unacceptable to block for a write to happen _when the buffer is full_, then you don't want to use `print` for your use case, since even when fully buffered it still can block _sometimes_. Granted, that "sometimes" can mean just long enough to hand off to a separate kernel-side buffer from the userland buffer the data was previously held in.

Comment: Most of these `print()` calls in question are sending log-type information to stdout.  Would using python's logging package be a more reliable way to save this information without introducing delays that may be associated with print?

Comment: Logging doesn't belong on stdout in the first place. Stdout is for _output_ -- the content your program is written to create -- where it's subject to pipelines/redirections/etc. Logging belongs on stderr, which is where the logging module puts it, where it's not prone to piping/redirections unless explicitly requested. (Granted, stderr by default is flushed even more aggressively than stdout is -- you don't want your logs cut off because they never got flushed when you're diagnosing a program that crashed -- but buffering is configurable for both descriptors, so that's fixable regardless).

Comment: Anyhow, it's starting to sound like you want to [increase Python's stdout buffer size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65021157/increase-pythons-stdout-buffer-size).

Comment: One of the roadmap items planned for my script is to eventually replace most of the `print()` calls to logging.  Where all that data goes is arbitrary, as long as it gets put somewhere.  I asked about logging, because if making the switch will also improve performance, perhaps that is the better way to go at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the implementation of `print()` in python which is essentially a write function with various formatting tasks.

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.2/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1986

It is possible to turn on non blocking file writes on unix, however, [turning on non-blocking mode has no visible effect for regular files](http://www.remlab.net/op/nonblock.shtml)

```py
f = os.open("fname", os.O_CREAT | os.O_WRONLY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
```

From what I understand write tasks fill a buffer [cached] and are written to disk after.

Furthermore on POSIX,

> That is, writes must be strongly consistent–that is, a write() is required to block application execution until the system can guarantee that any other read() call will see the data that was just written.
> https://www.nextplatform.com/2017/09/11/whats-bad-posix-io/

Comment: Whether there's a buffer depends on the details. If stdout goes to a TTY, it's line-buffered by default; a non-TTY destination is "fully buffered" by default, where flushing isn't content-triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you use Python's print() function, it's usually a blocking thing. Basically, it writes whatever you want to say to the console, and while it's doing that, everything else waits around until it's done

Comment: Usually? When does `print` not do this?

Comment: @Woodford, ...well, for one, `print` is not guaranteed to block until content is flushed all the way to the console if you set `end=''` and are writing less than a line.

Comment: And if stdout isn't going to a terminal _at all_ then you get entirely different behavior optimized for throughput (by trading against latency).